# ajax not sendind data to php

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

I have a function that is supossed to send data to a php file..although i get an alert that shows the correct ID and a success message, when trying to echo it out in my process.php, nothing is showed..the function is in adopt.php, the file that refers to process.php:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#loginform').submit(function(e){
        return false;
      });

   <?php
        $q = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM caini_donati");
            while($res = pg_fetch_assoc($q)){ ?>
                $('#<?php echo $res['id_caine']; ?>').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" }); 
    $("#<?php echo $res['id_caine']?>").click(function(event) {            
        var id_caine = event.currentTarget.id;            
        alert(id_caine);
        $.ajax({                
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',                                                
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data: { id_caine : id_caine},                                
            success: function(data){
                alert("succes"),
                console.log(data);
            }, error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {alert ("Error:" + xhr.responseText + " - " + thrownError );}

        });                       
    });                   
        <?php } ?> 
    }); 
</script>

 in process.php i have:
<?php
    $var = $_POST['id_caine'];
    echo "tr1: ".$_POST['id_caine'];
    echo "try: ".$var;
 ?>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? In process.php i want to run an update query based on the 'id_caine' variable..Any ideea is apreciated..Not important but I have altmost no knowledge about ajax.

Comment: Changing the url to: '/process.php' will show me an error alert saying the page is not found on the server..

Comment: Your problem is you are attempting to execute javascript on the server when you should be `echo`ing that js to the browser inside a `<script>` block so it can be run on the browser.

Comment: Ok, got that...but is there anyway I could send the variable to php giving that i want to run an update query based on that variable?

Comment: Your JQuery code looks ok, its just that it is not being sent to the browser so it is never actually being run.

Comment: I know and it's so frustrating..Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RiggsFolly is correct, you are missing the javascript html tags, i have tweaked your code to show you where they should be. Also i corrected the success method so that you actually had a variable to work with. You defined rs as the parameter but then tried to use "data" instead.

```
<?php
    $q = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM caini_donati");
    while($res = pg_fetch_assoc($q)){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#<?php echo $res['id_caine']; ?>').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" }); 
        $("#<?php echo $res['id_caine']?>").click(function(event) {            
            var id_caine = event.currentTarget.id;
            alert(id_caine);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                type: 'POST',                
                data: { id_caine : id_caine},                
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data){
                    alert("succes"),
                    console.log(data);
                }, error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {alert ("Error:" + xhr.responseText + " - " + thrownError );}                
            });                       
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but when adding the post, i totally forgot to also add the <script> tags before <?php ..?>..I'm trying to sort this out for over 5 hours, so sorry for my mistake, and also for the rs variable..don't know how I overlooked that...anyway...still not working :))..i've modified your remarks..Thank you!

Comment: mmm very odd, here is the code that I am using to test, I have stripped off the postgress call and removed the binding to the dom elements https://gist.github.com/rdelpeso/923c21397aa218e60f4c download that and save it as test.php locally or in your server and test there. I am curious as to what will be the output in the console with it.

Comment: I did it!! Thanks to you guys! I think i was about to give up..Following your advice, I watched the output in the browser console, and saw that the variable was actually echo-ed in the console, but when accessing process.php, it still wasn't available..i can't explain why but I managed to run my query anyway based on the variable..and one other thing..i don't know if it has any effect, but i used data: { 'id_caine' : id_caine} instead of data: { id_caine : id_caine}...Thank you so much!!!